# Error con Listener

Tags: android

En el MainActivity necesito implementar un  listener, que pueda recibir un dato  (boolean statusWIFIX) que mande TcpClient, La clase TcpClient está siendo usado en MainActivity, osea esta instanciado ahí,

Esta es mi codigo de mi TcpClient:

```
public class TcpClient {
.
.
public Boolean statusWIFIX = false;
private TcpListener1 mTcpListener1;
public TcpClient(TcpListener1 tcpListener1) {mTcpListener1 = tcpListener1;}

interface TcpListener1 {
    void onReportStatusWIFIX(boolean statusWIFIX);
}

public void stopClient() {

    statusWIFIX = false;
    // Report status to listener (MainActivity)
    mTcpListener1.onReportStatusWIFIX(statusWIFIX);

    Log.e( "DEBUG-->", "Coneccion Cerrada: "+ statusWIFIX );
    sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION+": " + Modelox);                // send message that we are closing the connection
}
.
.
```

Y este es el codigo de mi MainActivity, en donde evaluó el valor de statusWIFI el cual usare para ocultar o poner visible un icono en la pantalla superior:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
...
private TcpClient mTcpClient;

private TcpClient.TcpListener1 mTcpListener1 = new TcpClient.TcpListener1() 
{
    @Override
    void onReportStatusWIFIX(boolean statusWIFIX) {
        if (statusWIFIX == true) {
            statusWIFI = true;
        }else{statusWIFI = false;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    mTcpClient = new TcpClient(mTcpListener1);
...
}
...
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuItem IconWIFI = menu.findItem(R.id.bt1_wifi);

if (statusWIFI == true){
    IconWIFI.setVisible(true);
}
if (statusWIFI == false){
    IconWIFI.setVisible(false);
}
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
... 
}
```

Pero tengo este error, alguien me podria decir como corregirlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Desde que clase instancias TcpClient?

Comment: No coincide el código que has pegado en la pregunta con el código que aparece en la captura de pantalla. En particular esta línea: `Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );` que es, precisamente, donde tienes el error por haber agregado `TcpClient.this` en vez de, simplemente, `this` como primer parámetro. ¿Podrías agregar algo más de código para conocer la definición de tu clase para saber si ella misma es una `Activity`? Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia TcpClient.this y this son el mismo, si da error es que TcpClient no extiende Context

Comment: Gracias @SanderRito , desconocía ese uso. Siempre he usado `this` como palabra clave, nunca como miembro de la clase, o propiedad.

Comment: @OscarGarcia this es la referencia a la instancia de la clase, algo asi como yo_mismo -> this.

Comment: @SanderRito , ¿podrías, si no es molestia, darme un enlace a la documentación oficial en la que se muestre esta característica? Te lo agradecería mucho. Como digo, este uso particular de `this` me era completamente desconocido. Siempre agradezco la oportunidad de aprender algo nuevo.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: @SanderRito , disculpa que te moleste de nuevo, pero no veo por ningún lado referencia a este caso de uso de `this` en ese enlace.
 Si te apetece, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90424/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-sander-rito).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No entiendo bien tu código, mas bien que intentas.

El error es que el intent no esta siendo incializado con los parametros correctos:

```
new Intent (context, class);
```

Al parecer to clase TcpClient no extiende Context asi que no puedes usar **this** como primer parametro.

Pero no estoy seguro que lo que estas haciendo es lo que quieres hacer: Veo que to codigo quiere **ABRIR** la una *nueva* activity de tipo MainActivity pasandole unos parametros, y ademas va a **ESPERAR** que MainActivity mande informacion de regreso. Esto no va a pasar información a una activity existente.

Es esto lo que realmente quieres? Si es asi entonces pasa un objeto de tipo Context en el primer parámetro del intent y listo.

Si no entonces hay mas opciones.

Me imagino que TcpClient esta siendo usado en MainActivity, osea esta instanciado ahi, si esto es correcto hay otras maneras de pasar información.

Si forzosamente quieres usar intents para pasar información, MainActivity necesita implementar un BroadcastReceiver que pueda recibir los intents que mande TcpClient.

Ejemplo Listener

Interface TcpListener:

```
interface TcpListener
{
  void onReportStatusWIFIX(boolean statusWIFIX);
}
```

TcpClient:

```
public class TcpClient {
  private TcpListener mTcpListener;
  ...
  public TcpClient(TcpListener tcpListener) {
    mTcpListener = tcpListener;
  }
  ...
  public void stopClient() { 
    statusWIFIX = false;
    // Report status to listener (MainActivity)
    mTcpListener.onReportStatusWIFIX(statusWIFIX);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity ... {
  ...
  private TcpListener mTcpListener = new TcpListener() {
    void onReportStatusWIFIX(boolean statusWIFIX) {
      [ Tu codigo que recibe el boolean y lo pasa a la función requerida]
    }
  }
  ...
  onActivityCreate(...) {
    ...
    mTcpClient = new TcpClient(mTcpListener);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sander Rito, me podrias dar un ejemplo, acabo de modificar y aclarar mi pregunta original

Comment: Usar en intent como lo estas poniendo solo "abriría" un nuevo MainActivity y no reportaría al MainActivity original. Yo usaria el patron de listener, es mas simple, facil de usar y sigue el mismo patron de comunicacion entre MainActivity y TcpClient. Cual ejemplo quieres? Uno con intents o uno con Listener?

Comment: Edite la respuesta con un ejemplo de listener

Comment: Sander Rito, he seguido tu recomendación pero tengo error en el MainActivity (ver al inicio)

Comment: @W1ll Segun el error solo tienes que poner public void onReportStatus..., El error indica que estas cambiando los privilegios de acceso del metodo. Los métodos de una interfaz son publicos por defecto, pero en este caso lo esta poniendo private, y esto gebera conflicto. Solompon el acceso public al principio del metodo y funcionará.

Comment: @W1ll recuerda en tu listener actualizar el menu después de cambiar la variable de estatus para que pueda verse reflejado el cambio. invalidateOptionsMenu() detona una actualización del menu y lo redibuja

Answer (score 2):

En el caso en el que tu clase no extiende de una `Activity` o `Fragment`  lo que se realiza es modificar el constructor de la clase para enviar el contexto, de esta forma lo podrías usar dentro de la clase:

```
public class TcpClient {

private Boolean statusWIFIX = false;
private Context context;

    public TcpClient(Context context){
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }
.
.
public void stopClient() {

   ...
   ...

    //*** usa el contexto para definir el intent.
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra( "mStatusWiFi", statusWIFIX );
    //*** usa el context aqui para iniciar la Activity.
    context.startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
   ...
   ...

}
```